# Prevent a document from being updated more than once, MongoDB with Flask

Tags: flask, pymongo, gunicorn

**Hey guys**

I need some help with my Flask + gunicorn + pymongo application.

**I have the following route:**

```py
@app.route('/test_update')
def test_update():
    

    doc_match = db.collection.find_one({
        '_id': 1
    })
    # {'_id': 1, 'rate': 0, 'already_edited': False}



    if doc_match['already_edited'] == False:
        db.collection.update_one(
            {
                '_id': doc_match['_id']
            },
            {
                '$inc': {
                    'rate': 1
                },
                '$set': {
                    'already_edited': True
                }
            }
            )
        
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'ERROR', 403
```

So, in this route my intention is that the document is only updated once. But that's not what happens in certain situations.

Example, I did a test by sending more than 1 request per second on this route /test_update and I got more than one update success. What was to be just a success.

After sending more than 1 request per second my document looked like this:

```py
{'_id': 1, 'rate': 3, 'already_edited': True}
```

And what is expected will be:

```py
{'_id': 1, 'rate': 1, 'already_edited': True}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I appreciate any help from you guys.

I've done a lot of research on this and haven't found anything related.

Comment: Why not do it with one update?  Something like, `db.collection.update_one({'_id': 1, 'already_edited': False}, {"$inc": {"rate": 1}, "$set": {"already_edited": True}})`.

Comment: Even using document validation in the mongodb query, this failure happens

Comment: You need to use an atomic operation where the query is included with the update, for example [`find_one_and_update`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) or [`update_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) ... like what I showed in my first comment.